# How to stop presenting iOS native player after invoked by UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am using `UIWebView` for playing YouTube videos. `UIWebView` directly fires the native player for playing these videos. I am displaying a loader with cancel button until the video starts playing. When I click the cancel button I need to hide the webview.

The problem is when I click the cancel button immediately I hide the webview but the native player is still presenting after hiding the webview.

Is it possible to stop presenting the native player when its webview is closed?